# Eclipse MOXy : @XMLRootElement based on attribute - possible?

Tags: spring, jaxb, moxy

I have a set of XML files, which contain different information but all have the same root tag. The tags look like this:

First file:

```
<node type="A"> ... </node>
```

Second file:

```
<node type="B"> ... </node>
```

and so forth. Now the question is: can I use an annotation expression like this to have JAXB serialise them into different types:

A.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "node[@type='A']/text()")
public class A { ... }
```

B.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "node[@type='B']/text()")
public class A { ... }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying isn't possible how you are trying to do it.

You could parse the XML with a StAX `XMLStreamReader`, peek at the attributes on the root element event, choose which class to unmarshal, and then call the `unmarshal` method that takes a `Class` and an `XMLStreamReader` as parameters.

Comment: That's a shame. I imagine this case happens quite a lot. At the moment the root element is replaced by something unique we can use, but that is cumbersome. Oh well, seems there is no other way.